# python exception not reported

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Python version 2.7.13

I was debugging an issue in my program. I use pycharm debug to find that there is a key error, dict try to get a key not exist in it, but there is no traceback reported. In my program, we use `sys.excepthook = <my_callback_func>` to catch the uncaught trace, it usually works, but in my issue, it didn't work, the code didn't enter `<my_callback_func>`.

Maybe there is some other try catch code which catch this exception but I can't find it, because the program is quite large and complex.

So here is my question, is there a way to find which try catch code capture this exception, I use pycharm debug tools, but when I step debug it, the code never go to the catch code. or maybe there is some other reason that the sys.excepthook not working.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: In any case, why not use `dict.get('key')` rather than `dict['key']` or catch the KeyError explicitly?